# Reporting services - If condition in query of dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I need to switch between 2 queries in SSRS Reporting Services, from same report. Queries have same column data, differences are only in group by clauses. I have created a boolean parameter which should decide what query should be executed, but I can't get in to work in Dataset Query designer. Can somebody explain what I should do to make It work?

How I did so far (in Dataset Query designer):

```
if @chooseSelect = 1
SELECT FROM....
group by...
else
SELECT FROM...
```

This returns me errors "**Query execution failed for Dataset**" & "**Invalid SQL statement**"

Comment: I had this a while ago and used the following. which worked a treat.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857090/group-by-using-parameters-in-sql

Comment: Use management studio to debug each SQL statement

Comment: @JonTout, thanks for that, but I allready solved in another way. nice to know though, but my problem with doing like that was also that in group by query I sum one column, and not in other query. So I had to do It like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used this trick like in [this thread:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6a7d304-9631-4605-8e48-73e5085c2fb5/how-to-write-if-condition-in-ssrs-dataset?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Only thing I changed is that I don't show column which fetches data from different query (column year in thread example) in my report. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369680/3374391

See the note there: **DummySP created should be same like SP1 Do the same for Dataset 2..and this works.**